# Integration OneSignal SDK integration in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, build.gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I am just adding OneSignal SDK in my build.gradle and on OneSignal dashboard it's show me a one user registered. But When I send a test message from OneSignal it's shown, Deliver to 1 user. But I am not getting my test notification on Debug Device. Below is my build.gradle setup of OneSignal. Sorry for the English and Thanks in Advance.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "maa.techme.fit"
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id: "1a2021c2-30af-4c7d-b73d-23af9caee2bb",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "1023896849600"]

    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.2"
```

Comment: Do you have a class that extends Application with OneSignal.startInit in it? As well, make sure you declare it in the manifest as well.
It's a good idea to hide your appId/projectNumber for future.

Comment: I am adding OneSignal.startlnit in my MainActivity.java just after super.onCreate line.

Comment: 'protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Start OneSignal Push Notification
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);'

Comment: It should be in the Application class, not in the Activity. See point 2 from here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup

Comment: @AdrianComan Yes am already add dependencies in app/build.gradle compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5, 3.99.99]'

Comment: I'm not talking about the gradle file. I'm talking about the YourAppClass extends Application

Comment: @AdrianComan Dear Adrian the OneSignal SDK documentation link you send me above, in that where to place point 1 in app/build.gradle. In documentation it's says 'add the following to the top.

Comment: @AdrianComan Where to declare in Manifest. I am not yet declare.

Comment: Ignore point 1 because you already did it. I told you to read point 2, not reread point 1. There's a tutorial link there in the page at the end of point 2 specifically for cases where you "Don't have a class that extends Application in your project"

Comment: Create New Class`public class OneSignalPush extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();`

Comment: And also add in Manifest with android:name=".OneSignalPush". Done with step 2 but still not receiving testing message from OneSignal. But in Dashboard 1 user registered shown.

Comment: @AdrianComan It's working now perfectly. I am received my first test push notification in my real device.Thanks a lot Adrian Coman, really Thankful.